# Nuxt3 screen width problem with mobile view

Tags: html, css, vue.js, nuxt.js, google-chrome-devtools

i have problem with mobile preview on dev tools.
HTML with on desktop size is fine. Problem only occur with mobile view.
Why HTML width is 400 pixels now?
Do you have any idea how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I don't really see any issue here. Your website is maybe not behaving as you'd expect CSS-wise but the devtools are totally okay here from what I can see. Is it a CSS issue or a devtools issue here? Here, you've set your width to be 400px wide, so the main container is 400px wide

Comment: where i've set width to be 400px?

Comment: Top of the page: `Dimensions: Responsive 400 x`

Comment: You can actually drag and drop the slider on the right of the viewport if you want to expand it (make it wider).

Comment: but this is the problem, if i set 400px on the top i expect screen total size to be 400px and it's not. its about 550. so i can;t test small screens

Comment: `it's about`? Please be sure of the exact size of the viewport here. It should not be different from 400px if you set it to 400px. Of course, you can have a zoom, or some weird screen configuration. But the viewport is working great here (never got any issues). Your CSS may be doing funky things, please do not mix the viewport and the actual result of your page. Maybe use an extension to mesure precisely the pixels. Also, you could give a try to Firefox, but the result should be pretty much the same.

Comment: so what i need to do to have everything correct?

Comment: Define correct. If your page behaves not as expected, check the CSS with your devtools inspector and start looking for weird margins, hardcoded width or any other possible CSS value that may break your mobile viewport. Also, I'd recommend starting mobile first the next time: I'd be far easier to debug and faster overall.

Comment: that's why i think it's Nuxt problem because there are no margins. just HTML width is not in tact with screen size on dev tools. and i have no idea hpw to fix t. For tablets its okey. just mobiles

Comment: First off, the devtools are okay here (behaving as expected). Nuxt is okay here too, since it's just a SSR meta-framework (it will usually not break a responsive view). Your image on the top right may be the culprit. Focus on the HTML/CSS and inspect all the elements.

Comment: Okey you are right. deletion of image solved the problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image on the top right was the main issue, removing it made the mobile view responsive again.